# Knockout JS Computed Observable also takes User input

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I am using Knockout with MVC Core web application. In my UI I have several input text fields. For example  FirstName,  LastName and FullName.

I am making FullName as computed observable. Here is my problem. 
  Case 1: Based upon certain condition I want to use the FirstName and LastName data to compute the FullName. (That is the usual case shown in examples).

Case 2: Based upon certain condition I want to read the input that user can enter in the FullName text field. Can someone help me how can I do achieve that.

```
  function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');

if(somecondition)
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
} else {
    return somevalueEnterned in the text box
```

}, this);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you can't put your logic into the computed itself. Use a separate observable for the text box binding, and then return one or the other depending on your condition.

```
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
  this.textBoxValue = ko.observable('');

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    if(somecondition)
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    } else {
      return this.textBoxValue();
    }
  }, this);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason Spake. It is sort of a hack but it worked.